# Lightest paths tree

Tags: algorithm

I need to write algorithms finding the lightest path tree in directed and weighted graph.
(should be efficient as possible)
I'm getting a vertex S and need to build a paths tree from S to all vertex that can be approach from S so the paths in the tree are the lightest ( path weight is the path without the ends)

I thought about first calculating all the distances from S And then for each path there will be a new weight:
The weight minus The ends
And then on the graph with the new weights to run dijkstra...

Will it work? Is it efficient enough? How to calculate the distances?

Comment: Are you looking for [Minimum Spanning Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) or [shortest path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) from single source? These are different problems. What is the criteria to determine solution A is better then solution B?

Comment: @amit Basically every vertex in my question has a value (non negative) . Then I have S source vertex and I need to build paths tree to all vertices can be approach from S

Comment: For 2 given trees - how do you evaluate if tree `T1` is better then tree `T2`? what is the criteria?

Comment: I don't understand.. The paths from S to the vertices should be the cheapest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comments suggest you are actually looking for the shortest path from a single source - to all vertices.

Have a look at how [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) works. The algorithm starts with a tree of size 1 (the source alone), and iteratively adds vertices to the tree. In the end, the tree created by dijkstra's algorithm, represent the shortest path from the source to each of the nodes in the graph.

Note that dijkstra's algorithm, needs a weight function on edges, while your weight function is on vertices. It can be solved easily by defining a new weight function `w':E->R`: `w'(u,v) = w(u)` (it works since you don't want to count the end).

Comment: is the complexity is same as dijktra's algorithm?

Comment: Yes. It can.be created while dijkstra's algorithm is running, by addinv a vertex to the tree once the algorithm found the shortest path leading to it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking for a [minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree).  The wikipedia page discusses algorithms.

Comment: Actually, his question and especially his comments suggest he is looking for shortest path to each vertex, and the title is just misleading. (especially the comment: `The paths from S to the vertices should be the cheapest`)